# How to label x-axis with reciprocal relationship in linePlotImageDisplay?

Tags: dm-script

I have a 1D array and the x-axis is labeled by the index of pixel (e.g. 1,2,3,4...) if I simply display it. Now I want to show 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 in x-axis. I know imageSetDimensionScale is able to scale the x-axis by a factor. But how to calibrate x-axis in such a reciprocal relationship?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

LinePlots only support *linear* scaling factors. The 'best' you can do is to specify that the units are reciprocal and still use the linear scale, i.e. make a graph like this:

[image]